# tikz - checkmarker node line width not match cross marker

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try below code to create a checkmark and crossmark, but the checkmark size not match the crossmark!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\cross}{$\mathbin{\tikz [red,line width=4pt,line cap=round] \draw (-0.5,-0.5) -- (0.5,0.5) (-0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,-0.5);}$}%
    \node[red] (A) {\checkmark};
    \node[red,right=of A,minimum width=1,minimum height=1] {\cross};
    %\draw[red] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to make both marker the same size?
[image]

Comment: you can vary the `scale` option and `line width`  option to get the desired result -- have a look at the answer below

Comment: did the answer meet the requirement -- if so request accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \newcommand{\cross}{$\mathbin{\tikz [red,line width=2pt,line cap=round,scale=0.2] \draw (-0.5,-0.5) -- (0.5,0.5) (-0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,-0.5);}$}%
        \node[red] (A) {\checkmark};
        \node[red,right=of A,minimum width=1,minimum height=1] {\cross};
        %\draw[red] (0,0) circle (1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```